# Relational algebra question

Tags: relational-theory

Here is the relational schema given :

```
employee (person-name , street, city)
works (person-name, company-name, salary)
company (company-name, city)
manages (person-name, manager-name)
```

Q: Find the names of all employees who live in the same city and on the same street as do their managers.

I find the solution somewhere : [image: Solution]

but solution seems wrong which is just after second natural-join sign there is no select statement sign and just after that sign, a predicate appears 0_o , in that, from where does that `manager-name` attribute comes from?. I am completely lost.

My solution seems to be long since I used the Cartesian-product , and the query is bit long (of which I'm not even sure it's right or wrong) :(

Comment: Is this a homework question?  Not sure if this is the right place for this...  DBAs administer RDBMSs.  I took database theory several years ago and have not had to look at this notation since then. ;-)

Comment: @Strommy This is not homework. I'm just studying DBMS theory first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER : Never Learned Relational Algebra but it looks interesting

From the schema given and your question, this is what the SQL should be:

```
SELECT
    emp_mgr.person_name
FROM
    manages emp_mgr
    INNER JOIN employee emp ON emp_mgr.person_name  = emp.person_name
    INNER JOIN employee mgr ON emp_mgr.manager_name = mgr.person_name
WHERE
    emp.street = mgr.street AND
    emp.city = mgr.city
;
```

Here is another query that only uses JOINs, no WHERE clause:

```
SELECT
    emp.person_name
FROM
    (SELECT A.person_name,B.street,B.city FROM manages A
    INNER JOIN employee B ON A.person_name = B.person_name) emp
    NATURAL JOIN
    (SELECT A.manager_name,B.street,B.city FROM manages A
    INNER JOIN employee B ON A.manager_name = B.person_name) mgr
;
```

The first query gets all employees who are managed and their managers in the form of a Cartesian Product. Then, it looks for a common street and city.

The second query collects personnel records (name,street,city) of employees and their managers and performs a NATURAL JOIN between the employess and their managers using (street,city).

If you can transalate both queries back to Relational Algebra, I think you will have what you are looking for. I believe the second may be of better help.

Comment: it's about as interesting as a soggy stick

Comment: @jcolebrand LOL. Maybe this should have been migrated to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/